# how can read files in directory and write to file

Tags: python-3.x

I want to write all mp3 files in a file that are in a certain directory.

I used this code

```
import os
path = 'P:\dn\test55'
wrname = r'P:\dn\path\test55.txt'
test_files = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith('.mp3')]
f = open(wrname, "w")
f.write(str(test_files))
f.close()
```

the file is also written, but it looks like this

```
['001-file.mp3', '002-file.mp3', '003-file.mp3']
```

but i want the file to look like this :

```
001-file.mp3
002-file.mp3
003-file.mp3
```

How can I change this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You are writing list to a file. Like this will work. `for s in test_files: \   f.write(s + "\n")` between f open and close. Remember add "\n" return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `write` method writes its input string in the file. You then need pass to write the actual string that you want in your file: the mp3 names separated by the `\n` character that means "go to line"

```
f.write("\n".join(test_files))
```

the join method of strings takes a list as input and then join the elements of the list separated by the string from which you call the method.